# how to pass a parameter by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Problem statement: how to return a modified parameter value while returning its modified status in javascript function

sample code:

```
var inputHtml = 'hello';

if(IsContentChanged(inputHtml))
    alert(inputHtml);
else
    alert('No content changed');

function IsContentChanged(inputHtml)
{
    if($.trim(inputHtml))
    {
        inputHtml = 'new text';
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;    
}
```

Comment: where is the comparison and logic for changed input text?

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures):

> All types except objects define immutable values. Specifically, **strings are immutable**.

So you have to return an updated string, no in-place edit is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this link..

You can pass object by reference and can use this methodology for your requirement.

**[Pass by reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)**

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var inputHtml = {text:'hello'};

if(IsContentChanged(inputHtml))
    alert(inputHtml.text);
else
    alert('No content changed');

function IsContentChanged(inputHtml)
{
    if($.trim(inputHtml.text))
    {
        inputHtml.text = 'new text';
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;    
}
```